# How to add live search function into Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have Japan postal zip code live search function. It works at my xampp. I tried to add this into Laravel app but the search doesn't work.

Here is my whole code which works at XAMPP.

https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/rnsftzg8/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jpostal-1006.appspot.com/jquery.jpostal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).ready( function() {
    $('#postcode').jpostal({
        postcode : [
            '#postcode1'            
        ],
        address : {
            '#address1'  : '%3',
            '#address2'  : '%4',
            '#address3'  : '%5',
            '#address1_kana'  : '%8',
            '#address2_kana'  : '%9',
            '#address3_kana'  : '%10'
        },
        trigger : {
            '#address1_kana'  : true,
            '#address2_kana'  : true,
            '#address3_kana'  : false
        }
    });

    $("#address1_kana").on("change", function() {
        var val = $("#address1_kana").val();
        val = "onchange_" + val;
        $("#address1_kana_onchange").val(val);
    });

    $("#address2_kana").on("change", function() {
        var val = $("#address2_kana").val();
        val = "onchange_" + val;
        $("#address2_kana_onchange").val(val);
    });

    $("#address3_kana").on("change", function() {
        var val = $("#address3_kana").val();
        val = "onchange_" + val;
        $("#address3_kana_onchange").val(val);
    });
});
</script>
```

What I tried is ...
First I save all js into public/js folder but it didn't work. So
I simple save js file app.blade.php which is header.
Then I save html code into index.blade.php.

I'm wondering why it works at xampp only? 
Could you teach me what I missing please?

Comment: is this what you want : https://jsfiddle.net/1gspcxj6/2/ ?

Comment: Dear Vincent G Thank you for answering me. Yes it is. I can run the js file at XAMPP. My goal is I would like to add this into Laravel.

Comment: do you have some errors in the javascript console ? first, you can try to include all your code (html + javascript) in the same blade template and if it doesn't work, you can paste your template code here

Comment: Yes I just did what you said. I paste whole code but no error.. Sorry I'm beginner I don't know how to look what you point at .I have Firefox Develoeper Edition.I open console now. Where should I look and check? Could you teach me please?

Comment: Dear Vincent G Is this what you need ? I copy all log and paste here https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/rnsftzg8/2/

Comment: maybe this can help you : https://vegibit.com/creating-a-layouts-template-in-laravel/

Comment: Dear Vincent G Thank you for helping me. I read the page you teached me but still doen't work. Do me a favor. Could you add this js function into your laravel project and does it work? You just type 1000005 then address shows up. Ohter zip code is 1000001 1000002 1000003 1000004 1000005 When you type it into Fisrt input field then automatically addrsses shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so (depending on your Laravel version, mine is 5.7) :

First, create a route in the "routes" folder like this :

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@test')->name('test');
```

You will be able to access to this road in the `/test` URL.

In your **TestController.php** file (usually in `app/Http/Controllers`), create a method :

```
public function test(){
    return view('test');
}
```

Then, in `resources/views`, create a file named `test.blade.php`

In this file, put the HTML part of this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dayLkp4s/

After that, you can split header, footer, scripts parts in other files to use them elsewhere.

**Useful resources**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade

Comment: Dear ＠Vincent G Thank you. but I know blade file and I can display html part in my Laravel project. problem is I can see the HTML degin but JS function are doesn't work. Is this postal code function work at your Laravel project?  if yes I would like to know what am I missing.

Comment: yes it works in my laravel project. if you copy paste the HTML of the jsfiddle in my answer in a blade template, it should works.

Comment: Dear ＠Vincent G  Thank you for testing the code. I build new Laravel app then add the code it works! clean laravel project can run the js code. that is good but...Well I have still problem I already have a laravel project has other js function and I wanted to add this postal code function so. I guess fisrt js code cdn are confiict maybe? but I have no idea how to figure out what is cause. Could you give me a advice? Here is my Laravel CDN js part Could you take a look what is cause? https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/4hLg83od/

Comment: do you have some errors in the javascript console ?

Comment: Dear ＠Vincent G Hi. Is this help you TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[] mail:223:1
CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token app.js:1:115592
TypeError: $(...).jpostal is not a function[] mail:180:17

Comment: please show your entire code so I can help you better

Comment: Dear ＠Vincent G Thank you very much for you saying that! here is a link you can download my whole project. This is Email contact form and I wanted to add this postal code function. Actually after I add this function Email form doesn't send value to next page haha. I really apreciate your help . https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a8ffe0f7dc4fadbf928ddc9c39cc77cf20190307145033/b1dc41

Comment: i understand the issue now. you have to include your scripts in the <head> of the `default_mail.blade.php` and remove them from the `index.blade.php`
be careful on the validity of your html structure. here you had multiple <head> part due to the extends of `default_mail.blade.php`
if you handle these issues, it should works fine

Comment: Dear ＠Vincent G Thank you for your big help. I tried what you teach me but still same. I will do it again so Could you give me some time please. I will try it again then I will report ^^

Comment: Dear ＠Vincent G I think this take more time of my skill so I will close  this issue now I really glad your big help. THNAK YOU SO MUCH. you are amazing person! THANK YOU.